# Bootstrap 3 navbar separated collapsed menu items and non-collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm trying to have "separated" menu items when the navbar is collapsed...

Here's what I tried so far but it doesn't look right when the navbar is not collapsed because the navbar will overflow to two rows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbar-main">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="favicon-32.png"></a>
        </div>

        <div collapse="isCollapsed" class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-xs">
                <li ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-class="{active: isActive(item.link)}">
                    <a ng-href="{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Navbar items visible when collapsed -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right visible-xs">
                <li ng-hide="isLoggedIn()" ng-class="{active: isActive('/login')}"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
                <li ng-show="isLoggedIn()"><p class="navbar-text">Hello {{ getCurrentUser().name }}</p></li>
                <li ng-show="isLoggedIn()" ng-class="{active: isActive('/logout')}"><a href="" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Navbar items visible when not collapsed -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
            <li ng-hide="isLoggedIn()" ng-class="{active: isActive('/login')}"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
            <li ng-show="isLoggedIn()"><p class="navbar-text">Hello {{ getCurrentUser().name }}</p></li>
            <li ng-show="isLoggedIn()" ng-class="{active: isActive('/logout')}"><a href="" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: what do you mean by the "two rows"?

Answer (score -1):

Let's simplifying an example that describes what you need to do

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="ps-content">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar visible-phone" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="brand">Navigation</div>

            <ul class="nav hidden-desktop hidden-tablet">
                <li><a href="#link_1">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- PS RHS menu items -->
            <div class="visible-tablet pull-right">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#link_1">Active link</a></li><li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#link_2">Second link</a></li><li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#link_3">Third link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-collapse pull-right">
                <ul class="nav pull-right ">
                    <li class="active text-right"><a href="#link_1">Actives link</a></li><li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li class="text-right"><a href="#link_2">Second link</a></li><li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li class="text-right"><a href="#link_3">Third link</a></li>


                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

Check this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/62477)

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help. That just adds an item to the navbar if it's viewport is a tablet. I need to have different items in the collapsed menu.

Comment: Could you please give an example for what you're trying to do?